# ActionListeners: for each button in GUI a seperate listener or one listener for all buttons?

Tags: java, class, button, coding-style, actionlistener

So I was wondering what is the better looking solution/what are the differences and what are things to think about when making the decision about making either several listeners (1 listener for 1 button) or just 1 `ActionListener` for all buttons in my GUI (about 10 Buttons) and getting the information about which button was pressed through `actionevent.getSource() == buttonname`.

What is the better style in your opinion? Is there a disadvantage on creating so many classes for several `ActionListeners`? Or will it not matter at all?

By the way, in my code im trying to stick to the model-view-controller organization.

Comment: Look here [MVC Java: How does a Controller set listeners to the children classes of a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027887/mvc-java-how-does-a-controller-set-listeners-to-the-children-classes-of-a-view) also look [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48915/mvc-layout-which-way-to-add-listeners-is-better)

Comment: Adhere to the single-responsibility principle: one listener = one button. You really don't want a 3-pages-long method containing a chain of if/else if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to have different ActionListener classes but grouping them by functional responsibility is a good practice in my experience.

I also suggest you relying on `ActionEvent#getActionCommand()` over `ActionEvent#getSource()` because you could handle an equivalent action from different UI components.

Comment: Upvoted for "grouping by functional responsibility"; If I have a simple order-tracking app, with users and their orders, it would make sense to have two `ActionListeners`: `UserListener` and `OrderListener`;

Also good point on `getActionCommand` - as you say, this allows multiple copies of buttons to trigger the same behaviour, in effect decoupling the action selector from the GUI-component name (a good thing).

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   //do your work here.
  }
});
```

This is the way to go for each button.

A long `ActionListener` interface object with multiple if else or switch statements is both clumsy and hard to maintain. 
Additionally, on each button press, the program has to go through a number of matchings to get to know what button was pressed. That is very expensive.

So, one `Button` ---> one `ActionListener` is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use lambdas, one per each button, e.g.:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener(e -> //do your work here);
```